# Aggregate and NA values

Tags: r, variables, aggregate, na

I've got a dataframe with 1000 observations.
 For each observation I got five variables. Now I'd like to create a new variable which is an aggregation from those 5 variables.
 I typed the following:

```
df$aggr_variable <- (1/5)*(var1+var2+var3+var4+var5)
```

I then got the new aggregated variable, but also a problem. If let's say observation 839 got a missing value `NA` in `var2`, but still values for the other four variables, it gives me `NA` in the aggregated variable.

How can I leave the NA's of the five variables out without having to leave out the whole observation when one variable contains an NA?

Comment: `df$aggr_variable <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: nice, it works, thx! now, if i only want to aggregate say var 1, var3, and var4, how can i only use these and leave out var2 and var5? since rowMeans uses all means this wouldn't work out...

Comment: `rowMeans(subset(df, select = c("var1", "var3", "var4")), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

According to your aggregate equation, you are computing the average value of these five  variables for each sample(row).

```
#some reproduciable data
df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(20,10,5),var2=rnorm(20,5,1),var3=rnorm(20,30,1),
                 var4=rnorm(20,0,1),var5=rnorm(20,3,3))
#generates some NAs:
df[11,5] <- NA
df[8,3] <- NA
df[9,1] <- NA
df[17,2] <- NA
df[11,2] <- NA

#aggregate by mean
df$aggr_variable <- apply(df,1,function(x){mean(x,na.rm=T)})
```